# Eclipse Installation: can't execute binary file

Tags: kali-linux, eclipse

I have been using java quite a lot recently and am trying to install eclipse IDE. My os is kali linux
which is a little unconventional but I believe it is still possible. So I went to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and downloaded "Eclipse IDE 2021‑03." Which said it worked on mac, windows and linux. Once the zip file downloaded I extracted it and went to the install-eclipse folder that appeared, inside it was a file called eclipse-inst, which was meant to be executable, I had seen a few tutorials on getting eclipse on kali and all of them said to execute this file from the terminal using ./eclipse, I tried this as root and on my normal account and both times I got the same error, bash: ./eclipse-inst: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error. I have some screenshots below also of what happened. In kali tuttorials of how to install eclipse when they execute the file it brings up a window that allows you to select the eclipse software you want. I have the latest version of java and openJDK installed so I don't what is happening...?

[What happened[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5NAr.png)

Comment: Execute `file eclipse-inst` to see what code is contained in the executable. The shown binary type has to match to your Linux version (e.g. x86_64).

Comment: Thats the thing, the file is x86_64, I am pretty sure kali uses that version which is why I'm confused, eclipse only provides two packages for IDE, one is AArch64 and the other is x86_64 , is there a way I can check which version of linux is installed?

Comment: try `uname -mpi` that will give you the architecture of the kernel.

Comment: Oh, I see what was going on, you're right my architecture is not correct, it is AArch64, not x86_64, I should have tried the other package, I was put of by the fact that the main installer for Linux eclipse didn't work. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: What device do you use? ARM64 is still a non-standard architecture you should always consider that. Typically only x86/x86_64 is supported.

Comment: I use a raspberry pi 4, but I changed the os to kali linux. If ARM isn't supported I think i'll probably just get intelliJ idea instead which works with my kernel version cause trying to change version takes a while.

Comment: Good luck. Both IDE are very large and require a lot resources. Especially because of the CPU you will require a lot patience.